# Looking to use handheld scanning device to update Magento product data

Tags: product

Hello and thanks for taking a look.  I am fairly new to Magento but have a high level question.  The problem is I have a warehouse full of products that are assigned locations.  I have a custom attribute for Bin Locations that each child/simple product have a unique location throughout the warehouse. Right now we have to write the SKU and location down and add them to products individually so they can print out on order invoices.  Is there any way to have a handheld scanning device or even a smartphone be able to scan a SKU and a product location and have it assigned to the simple products in a specific custom attribute field?  Basically taking out the manualness of going to each product and adding it.   An app of some sort or a fairly easy interface where I can scan an item and the location barcode and it's assigned to the product in Magento?

Thank you in advance for any direction!

-Rob

Comment: Yes you can do it by scan barcode  with one extra column which also create in magento backend with any barcode device and store that value in excel sheet(bulk product )  so you can import /update product through excel